# How to display registered user asked questions using CouchDB with GWT in Java?

Tags: java

I am using CouchDB database where user asked questions are there, I need to display in link form so that when anybody wants to answer that, he can click on it.

I have tried to `getalldocuments` of my database and stored it in `arraylist<string>` and in `uibinder` file. I have created html object and stored the array in `verticalpanel`.

```
a1.display(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(String value:result) {
            HTML html = new HTML(value,true);
            //VerticalPanel p=new VerticalPanel();
            //p.add(html);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I would recommend you to provide a clear question in order to get help.

Comment: sir actually i m using couchdb where i have questions documents now i want them to display it on user page so that if anyone wants to answer that he can click on it and give answer to that particular question .